# No errors but nothing happens when I run (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays

Simple program that reads 6 numbers from keyboard and returns the sum of all the even numbers. But when I run this, it doesn't print anything and just quits.

What am I missing here? (I *know* vector would be better but I'm practicing for finals and this is an old finals question that specified using arrays).

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

void readNumbers();
void sumOfEven(int arr[6]);

int main(){
    void readNumbers();
    return 0;
}

void readNumbers(){
    int myArray[6];
    cout << "Enter 6 numbers:" << endl;
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
        cin >> myArray[i];
    }
    sumOfEven(myArray);
}

void sumOfEven(int arr[6]){
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++){
        if(arr[i] % 2 == 0)
            sum = sum + arr[i];
    }
    cout << "Sum of even numbers: " << sum;
}
```

Comment: `void readNumbers();` This declares a function, it doesn't call it. In `main`, make it `readNumbers();`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik That did it! Thanks!

Comment: @EliSadoff I don't see anything obviously wrong with `sumOfEven` What do you believe is a problem with it?

Comment: Never mind. I confused myself. Ignore me.

Comment: Compile with all warnings & debug info (e.g. `g++ -Wall -g`). Improve your code till you get no warnings. Then **use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`) to run your program step by step and query its state. Repeat till you consider that your program is correct.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Answers go in the answer section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In main there is a function declaration instead of a function call

```
int main(){
    void readNumbers();
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return 0;
}
```

You should write

```
int main(){
    readNumbers();
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    return 0;
}
```

The second problem is that you use incorrect indices in the loop

```
for(int i = 0; i <= 6; i++){
               ^^^^^^^
```

There must be

```
for(int i = 0; i < 6; i++){
               ^^^^^
```